# How can I rewrite postgres code to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update

I have a piece of code on plpgsql like that:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = value1
FROM table1 tbl
INNER JOIN table2 tbl2 ON tbl2.id = tbl.id
WHERE table2.code = 200
  AND table1.id = tbl.id;
```

Here table1 and alias tbl are two different table due to postgress specification. 
Now I want to write the same procedure for SQL Server, but this code fails with error

> [S0001][4104] The multi-part identifier "table1.id"  could not be bound.

How should I rewrite this code for SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler in SQL Server, because the `UPDATE` can reference an alias in the `FROM`.  There is no need to `JOIN` back to the original table.

So:

```
UPDATE tbl
  SET column1 = value1
  FROM table1 tbl JOIN
       table2 tbl2
       ON tbl2.id = tbl.id
  WHERE tbl2.code = 200;
```

This assumes that `id` is the primary key of `table1` (a reasonable assumption).

Answer (score 0):

You could use common table expression:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT tbl.column1
   FROM table1 tbl
   JOIN table2 tbl2 ON tbl2.id = tbl.id
   WHERE tbl2.code = 200
)
UPDATE cte SET column1 = value1;
-- SELECT * FROM cte
```

By highlighting and running only select statement inside cte you could check the result before doing actual update.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d4a2d4c73d2d6c09c2a3386572334d14)**